# How to run SCARF web application

Tags: php, sql

I want to run SCARF-2007-2-27 web application by xampp, But when I run it in htdocs directory of xampp, it gives me this error:

Table 'scarf.users' doesn't exist

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of an error in install.php code. so follow these steps to solve your problem.

1- open config.php in a text editor and set parameters like this:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "scarf";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "scarf";
?>
```

2- Open install.php in a text editor and:

2-1- remove line 1:

```
<?php include_once('header.php') ?>
```

2-2- at line 10 and 44 remove ' before and after false

2-3- at line 229 replace `<?php print genpassword(16) ?>` with 123

3- open install.php in a browser

4- make sure form fields filled correctly.

```
    Administrator username : <root user of sql>
    Administrator password : <password of root user>  
    Database hostname      : localhost
    Database name            : scarf
    New Username             : scarf
    New Users Password   : 123
```

5- click on the create database button.

6- open index.php on your browser.